# Is it possible to create a canvas inside of a class

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am currently working on a project where I have to have a grid made of points...
It seems that the code of the class is ok because there is no error message.
Could it be that you can't create a canvas inside of a class?
Thanks for helping me.
Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class grid():

    def createcanvas(self, master, width, height):
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, width=width, height=height)
        return(self.canvas)

    def createlabel(self, master, textu):
        self.l = Label(self.c, text=textu)
        self.l.pack()

    def createpoints(self, master, gridsize): # gridsize format '8X8'
        gridsize = gridsize.split('X')

        for i in range(len(gridsize)):
            gridsize[i] = int(gridsize[i]) #[8,8] for example --> x,y coordinates
        spx = 0
        spy = int(canvas['height'])
        for i in range(gridsize[1]):
            for j in range(gridsize[0]):
                master.create_oval(spx, spy, spx+5, spy+5)
                spx = spx + (int(canvas['height'])/gridsize[0])
            spx = 0
            spy = spy - (int(canvas['height'])/gridsize[1])



canvas = grid()
canvas = canvas.createcanvas(root, 600, 600)
a = grid()
a.createpoints(canvas, '16X16')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, you can create a canvas inside a class. Your own code seems to prove that. Why do you think the canvas isn't being created?

Comment: Well I ran the program and it just showed my root.

Comment: You haven't called `grid`, `pack`, or `place` on the canvas, so it's going to be invisible until you do.